# how can we load orcdata into hive using nifi hive streaming processor

Tags: hive, apache-nifi, orc

I have orc files and their schema i have tried loading this orc files in local hive and its working fine, now I will generate multiple orc files and need to load this orc files to hive table using nifi put hive streamming processor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PutHiveStreaming expects incoming flow files to be in Avro format. If you are using PutHive3Streaming you have more flexibility but it doesn't accept flow files in ORC format; instead both of those processors convert the input into ORC and write it into a managed table in Hive.

If your files are already in ORC format, you can use PutHDFS to place them directly into HDFS. If you don't have permissions to write directly into a managed table location, you could write to a temporary location, create an external table on top of it, and then load from there into the managed table using `INSERT INTO myTable FROM SELECT * FROM externalTable` or whatever.

Comment: Is there a more in-depth discussion about PutHiveStreaming vs PutHive3Streaming somewhere?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Besides PutHiveStreaming being made for Hive 1.2.x and PutHive3Streaming for Hive 3.x, the former uses Hive Streaming API v1 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Streaming+Data+Ingest) and the latter uses Hive Streaming API v2 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Streaming+Data+Ingest+V2)